# Req.body is empty on post request in Nodejs (Angular 4, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I try to make a POST Request to MongoDB

First I use service in Angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postTask(task) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/tasks', task, {
      headers: headers});
  }
}
```

And use it in component like this:

```
 postData(data) {
    this.service.postTask(data).subscribe( (res) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

The console.log gives me a string.

The problem is that when I try to post data, I can't pass the req.body, the argument, which has to be posted. **The console.log(req.body) returns {} for me.**
If I pass string like 'test3' (is right now in example so), the request will be posted. How could I pass the argument (req.body)?

Here is how I post it to DB

```
const app = express();
//Middleware for CORS
app.use(cors());

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

  var todoSchema = new Schema({
    taskName: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    isDone: Boolean,
    prioraty: String
  }, {
    collection: 'tasks'
  });


var Model = mongoose.model('Model', todoSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/admin').then(() => {
  console.log("connected");
}).catch (() => {
  console.log("not connected");
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
  console.log('mongodb connected.');
});



//Save Task
app.post('/tasks',  function(req, res) {

  console.log("Here is req2", req.body);
  var savedata = new Model({
    'taskName': 'test3',
    'isDone': false,
    'createdAt': Date.now(),
    'prioraty': 'medium'
  }).save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    }
  })
});
```

PS. In console the payload is here, so it should work..

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the `Content-Type` header. Angular will default to json. You're setting the content type to text in Angular, but configuring the Express body parser use use json.

Comment: @Brandon I tried with different types of header and also without it - it still doesn't work

Comment: Express is expecting JSON. It appears you're posting a single string value. Try sending a valid JSON object: `{ "task": "myTest" }`

Comment: @Brandon it works, when I set "test3", which is string too, so I guess I should just set instead the test3 the req.body, which is {} for now

Comment: As long as the value of the post is in JSON format, Express should be able to parse it from req.body.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks! it helped!

Comment: You're welcome.